# Bundler: Initialize with currently installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, dependency-management

How can I initialize/create/generate a `Gemfile` for [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) using the Gems I currently have installed?

For example, if I have the `rails` gem and the `colorize` gem already installed, and I start a new rails app, how can I generate a `Gemfile` that already includes the `rails` and `colorize` gems, ideally with their current versions, so I don't have to type them out manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Appending Installed Gems to Your Gemfile

You can dump all your currently-installed gems into a Gemfile-like format with a little Ruby text munging and shell redirection. For example:

```
ruby -ane 'puts "gem #{39.chr}#{$F.first}#{39.chr}"' < <(gem list) >> Gemfile
```

You could then manually edit the Gemfile and remove the gems you don't want, or organize them into [Bundler groups](http://bundler.io/groups.html) as needed.

Removing gems you don't want in your bundle might take longer than just typing them into the Gemfile in the first place, but your mileage may vary. At least it's nice to know it can be done!

Comment: You should accept the answer so CodeGnome gets the karma :-) (Accepting is separate from up-voting.)